# Python row/column confusion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
>>> b = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> b[0,2]
3
```

From this code it is clear that the first list that you pass ([1,2,3]) becomes the first ROW and not the first COLUMN of the 2D array.

```
>>> np.apply_along_axis(sum, 0, b)
array([12, 15, 18])
```

Why doesn't this give me array([6, 15, 24])? I set 0 as the axis which means rows. The sum of the first row is 6, not 12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html):

> Axes are defined for arrays with more than one dimension. A 2-dimensional array has two corresponding axes: the first running vertically downwards across rows (axis 0), and the second running horizontally across columns (axis 1).

So if you want to sum in first row it'll be across columns and you need to change axis to 1:

```
In [194]: np.apply_along_axis(sum, 1, b)
Out[194]: array([ 6, 15, 24])
```

Or you could do it with sum method of the numpy array:

```
In [198]: b.sum(axis=1)
Out[198]: array([ 6, 15, 24])
```

Comment: Okay I misunderstood "Apply a function to 1-D slices along the given axis." (I'm not a native speaker maybe that's why). I thought it means you walk along the specified axis and slice out the 1-D vectors (like rows in case of axis=0) :D Thank you very much!